# Configurable product pricing, 2 attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, pricing

I've ran into a bit of a problem (Magento 1.9.2.4) which I can't seem to figure out. Hopefully, someone may have an answer to my question.

Basically, I'm trying to create a configurable product with two different attributes:

- A - Dimension
- B - Colour

Now, each dimension has its own price. At the same time, with any other colour than white, the product price increases by 25% in relation to the price of the chosen dimension.

Which is something I can't seem to re-create in Magento.

Let's say:

- **Dimension A, white colour**, costs 10 USD.
- **Dimension A, red colour**,    costs 12,5 USD, aka, 25% more than the
  original 10 USD.

This is all nice and dandy.

The problem is, after setting the price rule for the red option (which is set as a 25% price increase), this happens:

- **Dimension B, white colour**, costs 20 USD.
- **Dimension B, red colour**, costs 22.5 USD, which is wrong, as it should
  cost 25 USD (25% more than 20 USD)

Magento seems to only consider the price of dimension A and does not take into consideration that dimension B might be priced differently than dimension A, and so the price should be increased by 25% of 20 USD, not by 25% of 10 USD.

Hopefully, my question is clear enough, if not, I'll be happy to shed more light on it. Is there a way to work around this?

Thank you for any help in advance :)!

Comment: A simple fix would be to use fixed prices – do you rely on relative prices?

Comment: Yes, I'm relying on relative prices, as the price increments for choosing red colour are different from dimension to dimension.

With dimension A, choosing the red colour increases the product price by 2,5 USD. With dimension B however, the price increase is 5 USD. With dimension C, it could be 10 USD or any other figure. Magento however, only lets you pick one value as the price increase for any of the attribute options, which is exactly why I thought using the relative pricing rule might work, but now I'm facing a different problem all together.

Thank you for your reply!